owned types are marked as extension [is an extension type, but there is no type definition for]
I am trying to run MOST MINIMALISTIC gateway but I am running into false positive error when one of the dependencies is thinking that Use Objet type is "extension" type.
Error: A valid schema couldn't be composed. The following composition errors were found:
        [auth] Type "User" is an extension type, but there is no type definition for "User" in any subgraph.

Auth Module:
@ObjectType()
@Directive('@key(fields: "id")') // this line breaks the gateway
export class User {
  @Field((type) => ID)
  id: number

  @Field()
  name: string

  @Field()
  email: string
}

@Resolver(() => User)
export class UserResolver {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  @Query((returns) => [User])
  users() {
    return this.userService.findAll()
  }
}

@Module({
  imports: [
    WrappedConfigModule,
    HomeModule,
    GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloFederationDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloFederationDriver,
      playground: true,
      autoSchemaFile: true,
      introspection: true,
      plugins: [ApolloServerPluginInlineTrace()],
    }),
    UserModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}

Events Module:
@ObjectType()
export class Event {
  @Field((type) => ID)
  id: number

  @Field()
  name: string

  @Field()
  description: string

  @Field(() => [Number])
  attendees: number[]
}

@Resolver(() => Event)
export class EventResolver {
  constructor(private eventService: EventService) {}

  @Query((returns) => [Event])
  events() {
    return this.eventService.findAll()
  }
}

@Module({
  imports: [
    WrappedConfigModule,
    HomeModule,
    GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloFederationDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloFederationDriver,
      playground: true,
      autoSchemaFile: true,
      introspection: true,
      plugins: [ApolloServerPluginInlineTrace()],
    }),
    EventModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}

Gateway Module:
@Module({
  imports: [
    WrappedConfigModule,
    HomeModule,
    GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloGatewayDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloGatewayDriver,
      gateway: {
        supergraphSdl: new IntrospectAndCompose({
          subgraphs: [
            { name: 'auth', url: 'http://localhost:8080/graphql' },
            { name: 'events', url: 'http://localhost:8081/graphql' },
          ],
        }),
      },
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}

You can run the code here: https://github.com/developer239/nest-microservices-example/tree/v2

Temporary fix can look like this:
`--- node_modules/@apollo/federation-internals/dist/schemaUpgrader.js.bak    2024-06-03 14:05:31
+++ node_modules/@apollo/federation-internals/dist/schemaUpgrader.js    2024-06-03 14:05:54
@@ -286,7 +286,7 @@
                 return;
             }
         }
-        this.addError(error_1.ERRORS.EXTENSION_WITH_NO_BASE.err(`Type "${type}" is an extension type, but there is no type definition for "${type}" in any subgraph.`, { nodes: extensionAST }));
+        // this.addError(error_1.ERRORS.EXTENSION_WITH_NO_BASE.err(`Type "${type}" is an extension type, but there is no type definition for "${type}" in any subgraph.`, { nodes: extensionAST }));
     }
     preUpgradeValidations() {
         for (const type of this.schema.types()) {
`

Keep in mind that the problem is likely caused by the directive decorator or by the underlying tech. I am still looking for actual answer.
